# Is there a way to refer to custom class object as to one of its properties/methods?

Tags: objective-c

For example I've got class:

```
@interface CustomClass: NSObject
    @property(nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *name;
    @property(nonatomic, readwrite) NSNumber *value;
    -(NSDictionary *)getDict;
@end

@implementation CustomClass
-(NSDictionary)getDict
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: @{}];
    if(self.name) {
        dict[@"name"] = self.name;
    }
    if(self.value) {
        dict[@"value"] = self.value;
    }
    return dict;
}
@end
```

Then I create instance of that class:

```
CustomClass *obj = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
obj.name = @"Custom object";
obj.value = @1;
```

Is there a way to get the 'name' property or getDict method when refering to that object? Like

```
NSLog(@"%@", obj);
```

will return for example only the 'name' property?

Comment: to get the dictionary call [obj getDict] and to get name NSString *name = [obj getDict] [@"name"]

Comment: Why won't you call `obj.name` instead of `obj` to retrieve it? If it's just for log, override `-(NSString *)description`, with something like `return _name;`, but that's misleading. It may be better to do `return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@ %p> name: %@, [self class], self, _name];`

Comment: that I know, but is there a way to NOT refer directly to property or method

Comment: it is for JSON creation puropse

Comment: for example I've got NSArray of my custom objects and I want to convert it to JSON

Comment: There is no need for the `if self.name`, you can safely assign nil to a dictionary entry. I understand what you are asking; you want to pass an instance of your object (or an array of your objects) to JSONSerializer. You can't do that. You will need to write a helper function to convert your array of objects to an array of dictionaries.

Comment: I do not know, what you mean with "indirectly". However, you can implement keyed subscription or simply use key-value coding. Is that, what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You should override `description` or `debugDescription`.

```
- (NSString *)description
{
   return self.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way (not sure if it's the right way):
My custom class is subclass of marker class MySerializable. Now if I've got an array of my objects, for every item in array I check if its of kind MySerializable and change that object in array to [object getDict].